# Two conflicting git remotes

Tags: git, branch, branching-and-merging

We had an issue with a bad merge that couldn't be undone cleanly (it reverted one of the branches, so it couldn't be merged back in). We created a new version of the branch from the last good commit, merged the new changes into it cleanly, deleted the original and pushed the new one to the remote repository.

However, now when we pull, it pulls from the deleted repository and pushes go to the new repository. If we `refresh prune`, the remote branch is no longer visible.

We have a branch with a temporary name that we're using as a stop-gap measure, but how do we get back to using the right name?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to delete the local branch, then recreate it, specifying you want to track the remote branch (the one with the right name)

That new local branch should this time pull from *and push to* the right remote tracking branch.

Comment: I've already tried that, with the results I describe above. When I say "track" it either refuses because it doesn't know the remote exists, or it succeeds but points to the deleted remote branch.

Comment: @CJDennis By remote, do you mean a remote name returned by `git remote -v`?

Comment: No, that returns a list of repositories, not branches.

Comment: Can you try in command line: git checkout -b mybranch origin/mybranch, to be sure it tracks the right branch?

Comment: `fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'mybranch' at the same time.
Did you intend to checkout 'origin/mybranch' which can not be resolved as commit?` I changed `mybranch` to the real branch name.

Comment: Did you delete the local branch first?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150140/discussion-between-cj-dennis-and-vonc).

Comment: I'm still checking chat but I'm working at the same time so I can't always reply immediately.